# npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<!doctype html><htm...'

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to install react on command line  `npm install react --save` and i am getting error message `npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<!doctype html><htm...'`

**I have already tried these options**

- npm cache clean --force
- npm cache clear --force
- Reinstalling npm and node
- Switching npm registry

Help how do i solve this and install successfully.

Comment: It appears that you have an html document somewhere in your tree instead of javascript. Look in the error to see where the file is and see if it is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Your package.json, or maybe other json file is incorrect, you must first fix JSON errors. After reading in the web I did "rm -f package-lock.json && npm install"
On this https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50837460.html you will probably find the solution to the problem

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)